# Variable depth of nesting inside Table

Tags: scripting

I need to create a table where there are variable number of iterators.

something like
`Table[s_1 *s_2 *... s_n,{s_1,1,5},{s_2,1,5},....,{s_n,1,5}]`
where n is a variable.

How to achieve this in mathematica?

Comment: Are you asking how to produce a template for arbitrary `n` or do you want to perform calculations with symbolic lists of an arbitrary structure? I think that Mathematica does not have (builtin) capabilities for the latter.

Comment: In other words, do you just need $s_1×s_2×...×s_n$ as 1st argument of `Table`, or you actually need $f(s_1, s_2, ..., s_n)$?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your ultimate goal, to produce those $s_1\ s_2\ ...\ s_n$ products, try the following instead, which should be equivalent to $s_i$ for $i=1$ to $3$:

```
n = 3;
Times @@@ Tuples@Table[Range[5], n]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 16, 32, 48, 64, 80, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125}

---

If you want the same list structure that would be generated by Table, then try

```
ArrayReshape[Times @@@ Tuples@Table[Range[5], n], ConstantArray[5, n]]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {3, 6, 9, 12, 15}, {4, 8, 12, 16, 20}, {5, 10, 15, 20, 25}}, {{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {4, 8, 12, 16, 20}, {6, 12, 18, 24, 30}, {8, 16, 24, 32, 40}, {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}}, {{3, 6, 9, 12, 15}, {6, 12, 18, 24, 30}, {9, 18, 27, 36, 45}, {12, 24, 36, 48, 60}, {15, 30, 45, 60, 75}}, {{4, 8, 12, 16, 20}, {8, 16, 24, 32, 40}, {12, 24, 36, 48, 60}, {16, 32, 48, 64, 80}, {20, 40, 60, 80, 100}}, {{5, 10, 15, 20, 25}, {10, 20, 30, 40,50}, {15, 30, 45, 60, 75}, {20, 40, 60, 80, 100}, {25, 50, 75, 100, 125}}}

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to define a function

```
variableNested[n_, f_] := Table[
  Evaluate[f @@ Table[s[i], {i, n}]], 
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{s[i], 1, 5}, {i, n}]]
  ]
```

which you then could call via

```
variableNested[3, Times]
(* {{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {3, 6, 9, 12, 15}, {4, 8, 12, 16,
    20}, {5, 10, 15, 20, 25}}, {{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {4, 8, 12, 16, 
   20}, {6, 12, 18, 24, 30}, {8, 16, 24, 32, 40}, {10, 20, 30, 40, 
   50}}, {{3, 6, 9, 12, 15}, {6, 12, 18, 24, 30}, {9, 18, 27, 36, 
   45}, {12, 24, 36, 48, 60}, {15, 30, 45, 60, 75}}, {{4, 8, 12, 16, 
   20}, {8, 16, 24, 32, 40}, {12, 24, 36, 48, 60}, {16, 32, 48, 64, 
   80}, {20, 40, 60, 80, 100}}, {{5, 10, 15, 20, 25}, {10, 20, 30, 40,
    50}, {15, 30, 45, 60, 75}, {20, 40, 60, 80, 100}, {25, 50, 75, 
   100, 125}}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tupleProducts = Times @@@ Tuples[Range[#], #2] &;

tupleProducts[5, 3]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 5, 
> 10, 15, 20, 25, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30,
> 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 6, 12, 18, 
> 24, 30, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 4, 
> 8, 12, 16, 20, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 16, 32, 48, 64, 
> 80, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 15, 
> 30, 45, 60, 75, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125}
> ```

```
partitionedTP = Partition[tupleProducts[##], #] &;

partitionedTP[5, 3]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {3, 6, 9, 12, 15}, {4, 8, 12, 16, 20}, 
> {5, 10, 15, 20, 25}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {4, 8, 12, 16, 20}, {6, 12, 18, 24, 30}, 
> {8, 16, 24, 32, 40}, {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}, {3, 6, 9, 12, 15}, {6, 12, 18, 24, 30}, 
> {9, 18, 27, 36, 45}, {12, 24, 36, 48, 60}, {15, 30, 45, 60, 75}, {4, 8, 12, 16, 20}, 
> {8, 16, 24, 32, 40}, {12, 24, 36, 48, 60}, {16, 32, 48, 64, 80},
> {20, 40, 60, 80, 100}, {5, 10, 15, 20, 25}, {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}, 
> {15, 30, 45, 60, 75}, {20, 40, 60, 80, 100}, {25, 50, 75, 100, 125}}
> ```

```
partitionedTP2 = Join @@ Outer[Times, ## & @@ ConstantArray[Range[#], #2]] &;

partitionedTP2[5, 3] == partitionedTP[5, 3]
```

> ```
> True
> ```